# Angular + Webpack + jQuery. Where is the configuration file?

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am using Angular 4.

```
@angular/core: 4.3.6
```

I am looking into using expose-loader to expose jQuery as a global variable. And multiple answers suggest using **expose-loader** by installing and editing the

```
webpack.config.js
```

file.

Although, I can't seem to locate it in my angular 4 app file tree.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, _how_ are you bundling your Angular app? The answers assume the standard name for the webpack config file.

Comment: Didn't quite follow. I build the app using the standard "ng build" and I created the app using "ng new ...". Was that, what you were asking?

Comment: If you're using the CLI, the webpack config is not exposed. This is the feature of the CLI. You'll have to eject the config to do what you want: `ng eject`.

Comment: Hopefully you are using `jQuery` in your angular app for a reason like want to use some ui widgets that depends on jQuery, otherwise better to avoid using jQuery.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that only `ng eject` exposes the webpack config. Yes, I am using jQuery only for its functional benefits, and the ui widgets not contradicting or going against the angular principles/ideology :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend to `--eject` `webpack.config` just for a sake of adding `jQuery`
You can avoid that just by doing:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

then import that in `.angular-cli.json` `scripts` section

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
],
```

and you should be fine
Use that as `import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same thing. Since the "ng serve" and "ng build" aren't expected to work the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install jQuery

   ```
   npm install --save jquery
   ```
2. Install jQuery type definition for type checking.

   ```
   npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
   ```
3. Add reference of jquery file in "scripts" array inside angular-cli.json file.

   ```
   "scripts": [
       "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    ]
   ```
4. import jquery in any component you want to use.

   ```
   import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
   ```

Comment: I posted the same answer just `2` seconds before ;)

Comment: @Kuncevic Sorry I do not saw. I'm writing answer in this moment

Comment: Thank you! Yep, I think I am going to go ahead this adding it to the `angular-cli.json`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the jQuery type definition file:

```
npm install @types/jquery
```

And also, in your `webpack.config.js` file:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery"
}),
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the "webpack.config.js" file